# Sort file in bash shell

Tags: bash, file, shell, sorting

I want to sort file, by the first number, which looks like this.

```
11: wc 
1:cmp: 
115:wc
7:ls
```

So i get output in file like this.

```
1:cmp:
7:ls 
11: wc 
115:wc
```

I've tried to sort it my self, but it doesn't work. This is my following code

```
cat dat | sort -t ":" -k 1 >dat;
```

What can i do? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `sort` command with numeric sort:

```
sort -t: -nk1 file
1:cmp:
7:ls
11: wc
115:wc
```

Comment: thank you it works! i used it like: cat $dat | sort -t: -nk1 >dat;

Comment: yes i just did. i couldn't do it before because you must wait like 5 min to mark it.

Answer (score 0):

For the sort part you can do

```
$ cat dat | sort -t: -k1,1n
1:cmp: 
7:ls
11: wc 
115:wc
```

But if you want to save the sorted lines to `dat` file again you should do

```
$ cat dat | sort -t: -k1,1n > dat_copy
$ cp dat_copy dat
$ rm dat_copy
```